# custom attribute vs data-* attribute

Tags: html, dom

I know that data- Attributes is part of HTML 5. It seems to be a good choice to use it to serialize some data in markup. So there are people using data-bind="xxx" . But can I just use  bind="xxx". It seems violate schema, of specification, but practically it works in all browser. So my question is, what is the practical reason (not in theory) like performance that I should not use customs attribute just like bind="xxx". I know bind attribute is not reserved attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Practically, some browser can implement `bind` with a totally different meaning.

You're using it for Knockout, but hypothetically the new meaning is different.  When you change the inline CSS on one element, it should change it on another element based on a selector in the bind attribute.

There's a reason to respect standards and use private (e.g. data-) or vendor-specific prefixes.

Comment: Let's say this page is my page, this attribute is nobodycareattributexceptme="xxx", "practically", what bad effect like (404, running out of memory, incorrect ui rendering) it will cause.

Comment: That's a hard to remember (and search) attribute name.  Other than that, I don't know of issues if you use an obscure name like that.  That doesn't mean there won't be any though.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I had the same question as Fred.  I found the answer and I wanted to share it.  There is no practical reason not to use an arbitrary attribute name other than what was mentioned in another answer.  That is a vendor or browser maker may decide to use the name for something else.

It is however not allowed in the spec, kind-of, while the spec does read that arbitrary attribute names should not be used, there is nothing preventing their use.  This is like the US Code for Displaying a flag, it's a set of rules but no way to enforce it.

Contrast this to a rule that is enforced such as a single body tag within an html document, etc. and you can realize that there is nothing enforcing using arbitrary names for attributes.

So what remains is why should you not use arbitrary attribute names?  Since it will not pass the W3 html validator, it can be argued that societal pressure may increase to the point that your code will not be acceptable.  For example, SEO may suffer, a future employer may not like sloppy code, etc.
I certainly became embarrassed as I make liberal use of arbitrary attribute names to pass data. Something that I will stop immediately.  I am now convinced that using the data-* attribute will make my code easier to read, easier to maintain and clean enough for peer review.