# HTML "data-attribute" vs simple "custom attribute"

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I usually saw html `data-attribute`(s) to add specific values/parameters to html element like Bootstrap that uses them to "*link*" buttons to modal dialog to be opened, etc.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
```

Now, I see that **an almost famous CSS framework, [Kube](http://imperavi.com/kube/),  in its new version extensively uses simple custom attribute** such as in following:

```
<column cols="4">4</column> 

<span class="label label-black" outline bold>Black</span>
```

Other in-action examples are visibile for example, [here](http://imperavi.com/kube/css/labels/).

I did not know that was possible to use simple custom attributes so I tried to search some source about this, and I found only [this old similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608236/custom-attribute-vs-data-attribute) in which are noted almost only (*possible*) compatiblity issues.

*I'm surprised that a CSS framework like Kube could use a similar solution if browser support could be so "fragile"....*

So my question are:

1. **How good** (=cross-compatible) **is Kube's approach?**
2. Can I safely replace my `data-attribute` with simple custom ones if for example I have to pass only true/false values?

This last question is better described by an example, so replace `<span class="foo" data-boo='true'>Black</span>` with `<span class="foo" boo>Black</span>`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework but a quick grasp at their site suggests they use good old `class`. Could you please point to an example of such usage?

Comment: I edit my question with a link to specific documention page in which you can find applied examples

Answer (score 17):

Use data attributes. They are:

- standard
- won't make a validator report them as errors (it's hard to spot unintentional errors in a validation report when they are surrounded with a pile of errors that you've made intentionally)
- won't conflict with attributes that might be added to the standard in the future

… and you don't have to give them values if you just want to check to see if they exist with a CSS attribute selector … but if you want that then you should probably just be using additional classes instead.

Comment: For what good reason would they make a validator choke? (i.e a reason that can't be reasonably avoided; not just for the reason that there is some validator out there that doesn't support it because it was poorly written).

Comment: @BVernon — Because arbitrary attributes that you make up are not attributes that the HTML specification permits.