# Access the label text of a datalist option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-datalist

I am filling a data-list in html using data from a Json . The options are being appended to the data-list with the value and label text . on click of an option , I want the value and the text to be inserted into a form text field .

The value of the option can be accessed and is successfully inserted into the text field. But I am not able to access the label of the option to insert it.

I have tried using $(this).innerhtml(); , $(this).text(); , $(this).label(); , $(this).innerhtml(); and so on..

all of which turned out to return null value (undefined) instead of the required string.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyJsonFunction")',
        datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                    
                $.each(data, function (index, data) { $("#myid1").append("<option value='"+data.Value+"'label='"+data.Text+"'></option > ");})},
        error: function () 
        {
            alert("Something went wrong!");}});

     $("#myid2").change(function () 
      {

         var s = $(this).val();
         var d = $(this).html();

         alert(d);

         $("#input1").val(s);
          $("#input2").val(d);
     });

});
```

The value of the option is being inserted to the input text field but the label of the option is null when i try to access it .

when i alert it , it displays either an empty string or "undefined" .

Comment: `label` in your code is an attribute you can use `$("option:selected" , $(this)).attr('label')` ..Also take a look at [HTML “data-attribute” vs simple “custom attribute”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151713/html-data-attribute-vs-simple-custom-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.you have to  make any one option as selected, because on form load,none of your options are selected and it will surely alert as undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$("#colors").trigger('change');
});
$("#colors").change(function ()       {
  var d = $('#colors').find("option:selected").val();
  alert(d);
  $('#selvalue').val(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label for="color">Favorite Color</label>
<input list="colors" name="color"> 

<datalist id="colors"> 
<option selected=selected value="Green"> 
<option value="Red"> 
<option value="Blue">
<option value="Yellow"> 
<option value="Orange"> 
</datalist>




<input type='text' id='selvalue' placeholder='Display seleted value'/>
```

Comment: still returns "undefined" when i alert .

Comment: it's not a select field first of all. It's a datalist linked to an input type of text. myid1 is the id of the datalist and myid2 is the id of the input field

Comment: @VishnuSayanthAV try my code its working. ive modified it.. just try and let me know

Comment: @VishnuSayanthAV Please provide us ur html content

Comment: <input type="text" id="adusersearch" list="adusers" placeholder="search Active Directory" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: <datalist id="adusers"> <option value="" label=""> </option> <option value="abc.singh"> abcSingh</option> <option value="wdc.Wong"> wdcWong</option> <option value="alex.xcv"> Alex xcv</option> <option value="a.s"> a s</option> <option value="qwe.rty"> qwe rty</option> < </datalist>

Comment: @VishnuSayanthAV try now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('change','#myid1',function(){ alert( $(this).find(':selected').attr('label') ) });
```

Please try this code. I am sure this will work

Comment: Still alerts undefined.

Comment: Look at this code and tell me if this matches your html structure or not.
If No then please share your html code.
<select name="" id="myid">
    <option value="A" label="AA">A</option>
    <option value="B" label="BA">B</option>
    <option value="C" label="CA">C</option>
    <option value="D" label="DA">D</option>
    <option value="E" label="EA">E</option>
</select>

Comment: It will be better if you can share the HTML from browser. Like inspect it and copy it.

Comment: It's not a select field actually. It's an input text field with a Data-List.

Comment: <input type="text" id="adusersearch" list="adusers" placeholder="search Active Directory" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: <datalist id="adusers">
                <option value="" label="">
            </option> <option value="abc.singh"> abcSingh</option> <option value="wdc.Wong"> wdcWong</option> <option value="alex.xcv"> Alex xcv</option> <option value="a.s"> a s</option> <option value="qwe.rty"> qwe rty</option> <  </datalist>

Comment: myid1  in the question is "adusers"  and myid2 is "adusersearch"

Comment: Try this code
$('body').on('change','#adusersearch',function(){
         console.log( $('#adusers option[value=' + $(this).val() +']').attr('data-label') );
        });